# get_comments_number() giving wrong results! What are alternatives?

Tags: plugins, comments

get_comments_number() function giving wrong results because of a plugin filter. Which function can be used instead of `get_comments_number()` ?

Answer (score 1):

`$counts = wp_count_comments();`

this will return total comments for blog

But if you want to get total comments of a post, then

`$counts = wp_count_comments( $post_id );`